# leveldbjni IO error LOCK: No such file or directory

Tags: java, redhat, leveldb

We're trying to use leveldbjni on redhat machines. It worked flawlessly on ubuntu. But on redhat it gives the following error:

org.fusesource.leveldbjni.internal.NativeDB$DBException: IO error: <file location>/LOCK: No such file or directory

We tried to create the leveldb C++ library on redhat (using instructions at https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni) and still got the same issue.

Comment: Do you have the proper RWX permissions set up on the directory you're operating? What operation are you getting that exception on?

Comment: I'd raised the question to hiram@hiramchirino.com, the developer of leveldbjni. He's also pointed to permission and/or SELinux. But it wasn't either. Besides I was running the application as root. Finally figured out that it just wasn't able to create the directories. e.g: If I specify a location such as /tmp/myleveldb then it will throw the error IO error: /tmp/myleveldb/LOCK: No such file or directory. But if I create the directory /tmp/myleveldb then it works fine. So my temporary workaround is to create the directories on getting this exception.

Comment: It seems reasonable that the library is not going to make a directory for you, rather you should make it instead.

Comment: Lirik, I wouldn't mind the default behavior of the library being that, its just that on ubuntu it creates the directories and on redhat it doesn't.

Comment: hmmm, that's really odd... it might be worth reporting that. However, I'm using leveldb in Windows and I have to create the directories too.

Comment: you use leveldb on windows? did u build it yourself from the source for windows? cause i tried a jar i found from a maven repo and it only works on linux based systems

Comment: Yes, I use leveldb on windows and I built it myself from the source. There were a couple of modifications we had to do, if I recall correctly, but it generally works pretty straight forward.